# Android ==> Simple Animation?

Tags: android, animation

How can i display a simple animation?

Let's say there is a button on the screen with margin left of 200, and margin top of 200.
I need to set the margin left, and top of this button to 0 and show a simple animation.

So basically a simple animation on a button from position 200,200 to position 0,0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are mainly 4 built-in Animations comes up with Android SDK:

1. AlphaAnimation – transparency changes
2. RotateAnimation – rotations
3. ScaleAnimation – growing or shrinking
4. TranslateAnimation  – position changes

So from these....You can implement `TranslateAnimation`.

You can refer  [Example here](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)  and also   [Android SDK - TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) .

Enjoy!!!

Comment: I'm on Mobile. I logged in just to up vote your answer. Andrew logging in via 2 factor is a pain in the a#& thanks for the succinct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `TranslateAnimation`.