# How to create a simple text animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I want to show a simple text animation in an android game. I have my `Canvas` and I want to paint the text animation in a particular area where I want to move the text from down to up and as it moves up it size will increase just like a bubble effect. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Following links :
It's may useful to create animation from starting:

[For Translate Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3217997/1318946)

[Simple Animation Part-1](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129)

[Simple Animation Part-2](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/137)

[Simple Animation Part-3](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/171)